# R: duplicate data in a dataframe

Tags: r, duplicates

Mars:

```
ticket  Name    Fare
  A3    Emily    50
  A4    Jack     50
  A5    Sam      25
  A6    Lara     25
  A4    Julie    50
  A3    Kevin    50
```

When we go to the movies, sometimes we buy one ticket for two people's price. Now I need to count the repeated data. I know how to count it, but not sure how to put it back into the data frame since the length will be different.

My code:

```
a <- as.data.frame(table(Mars$ticket))
Mars$Count <- Mars$ticket[a$Var2]
```

Output:

```
var1   Var2
A3      2
A4      2
A5      1
A6      1

Error
  replacement has 4 rows, data has 6
```

Expected output:

Mars:

```
ticket  Name    Fare  Count
  A3    Emily    50     2
  A4    Jack     50     2
  A5    Sam      25     1
  A6    Lara     25     1
  A4    Julie    50     2
  A3    Kevin    50     2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `merge` like this

```
df <- read.table(text = "ticket  Name    Fare
A3    Emily    50
A4    Jack     50
A5    Sam      25
A6    Lara     25
A4    Julie    50
A3    Kevin    50", header = T)

a <- as.data.frame(table(df$ticket))

merge(df, a, by.x = "ticket", by.y = "Var1", all.x = T)

  ticket  Name Fare Freq
1     A3 Emily   50    2
2     A3 Kevin   50    2
3     A4  Jack   50    2
4     A4 Julie   50    2
5     A5   Sam   25    1
6     A6  Lara   25    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that 'ticket' is `character` class, we use the 'ticket' to match the `names` of 'table' and expand the values

```
Mars$Count <- with(Mars, as.vector(table(ticket)[ticket]))
Mars$Count
#[1] 2 2 1 1 2 2
```